# Why fingers bones don't bend properly?

Tags: animation

I'm new to animation and rigging in Blender, matter of fact new to blender. But I want to learn rigging and animation right now, and I've setup this rig:

And everything moving the large standing bone at the palm of the hand moves the entire arm properly. Yet when I try to curl/bend the fingers into a fist pose, here's the result:

[image: Front]

[image: Broken fingerzzz]

Basicly I've setup the finger bones to copy rotation on Z axis from floating curl control bones. That's all. Any ideas?

Comment: it coud be a rigging problem (wrong bones rotation) or weighting problem (mesh not following a correct bone rotation)... but you didn't show where the bones are, here...

Comment: I'm sorry,  stack exchange didn't allow me to upload more than two links:

[link]http://imgur.com/a/hNopm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be fixed by adjusting your weight paint. Try distributing the weight more accurately according to the vertices. It should fix your problem.

Comment: I've tried adding more weights / removing but nothing seems to work... I've tried removing weights everywhere except the actual finger didn't work. I tried adding more weight on the palm of the hand (area close to the fingers) and that didn't work...

Comment: Perhaps you could use this link to attach your .blend file so that I can view it and maybe figure out what's wrong with it: blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: That would be very kind of you!

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2090" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2090/)

Comment: I've done a little bit of changes to your original file. Mostly, I've adjusted the length of each finger bone so that the joints match up more evenly for each finger. Then I've done a little changes to the weight paint, although you could touch it up further.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2091" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2091/) Here's the edited file. Hope it's what you wanted :D

Comment: Oh wow! That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help! Appreciated