# Is there a way to make a shape key (or vertx group) blend along bone movement rather than linearly between start and end points of the vertex?

Tags: bones, shape-keys

Still learning and messing around and can't figure how to do this or if it is possible at all.

Best way to describe what I'm seeing is if you imagine a finger curled tight as the the start point and it out stretched as the end point, rather than uncurling the vertex points seem to mostly trying to straight line to their end point of the shape key rather than maintaining a finger shape and I get shrinking and ballooning as a result.

What I want if for the shape to remain mostly intact rather than 'wither' and collapse while morphing between start and end points. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

-KD

Example File - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BqibHZXHuNuyNlJlniEy20b3_9IoSNRh

Comment: Shape keys always make vertices moving in straight lines with the shorter possible path; bones are maden for more complicated movements: you will have to build your armature following the structure of real hand bones. Take a look at this answer for an example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64794/why-fingers-bones-dont-bend-properly. If you want a more accurate answer, please upload your file.

Comment: I have the bones working in pose mode fine and they do what I need there. It's the shape key blend that I was wondering if there is a way to control. (Will add a file to original question as an example in a moment)